# Link between maps $C^\infty(M) \times C^\infty(M) \rightarrow C^\infty(M)$ and bivectors.

Tags: differential-geometry, poisson-geometry

I was reading a bit [these notes](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Eruiloja/Math595/book.pdf) on Poisson geometry.

At some point, the author establishes a connection between bi-vectors and maps $C^\infty(M) \times C^\infty(M) \rightarrow C^\infty(M)$ and says.

> we can define a bivector field $\pi ∈ \mathfrak{X}^2(M)$ by:
>
> $\pi(df,dg):=\{f,g\}$.

But how is $\pi$ defined for the 1-forms that are not exact?

Comment: I think the idea is that in local coordinates $x_1,\dots,x_n$, $\Omega^1(M)$ is  generated by $dx_1,\dots,dx_n$ as a $C^\infty(M)$-module. Since $\pi$ is supposed to be $C^\infty(M)$-bilinear, it's completely determined by $\pi(dx_i,\, dx_j) = \{ x_i, x_j \}$.